# How does this transformation actually happen?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, aerospace-engineering, fluid

I cant exactly give you the  complete relevant details of the variables but assume the following (bold means vector):

**B(x)** ~ $\frac{1}{8\pi}*(\nabla\frac{1}{r})\times\int \mathbf X'\times \mathbf \Omega' dV(\mathbf X')$

where r=|**X-X'**|, prime denotes evaluation at point **X'** and dV is the volume throughout the domain and it holds as $r \rightarrow \infty$

Let this integral be evaluated for a large value of r (say R). My question is why is the following possible if the above integral holds on a spherical surface,

$8\pi R^2(\mathbf n \times \mathbf B)_{r=R} = \int \mathbf x \times \mathbf \Omega dV - \mathbf n \mathbf n. \int \mathbf x \times \mathbf \Omega dV$

For exact reference see pg 519 of the book in the link [Fluid Dynamics by G.K.Batchelor](http://users.df.uba.ar/cobelli/Libros/Batchelor.pdf). What I am asking about is the derivation between equation 7.2.3 and 7.2.4. Though this book is considered a classic, but damn its hard to keep up with these technicalities.

Comment: I assume $\mathbf{n}$ is the outer normal to the sphere, can you clarify what you denote as $\mathbf{nn}$? Plus $\mathbf{X’}$ is inside and outside the integral (outside via $\mathbf{r}$ : Do we have to assume that it is constant ?

Comment: Can't say how the expression is derived (probably using several vector identities).  However, note is that $\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{n}\mathbf{n}$ is a projection operator that projects $\mathbf{P} := \int \mathbf{x} \times \mathbf{\omega}\,dV$ on to the surface of the sphere.

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee Hmm...i didn't think of that. But I still cant relate the cross product with the projection operator.

Comment: @H.C.Lefevre ..cant exactly say. I initially took it as dot product but i couldnt make anything out of it. As i have said, you can check page 519 of the  link. There too it just mentioned **nn.**. **X'** in the volume integral means, volume being calculated with **X'** as the origin. I hope this helps atleast for the second part, and sry that i couldnt help with the first part

Comment: $\mathbf{n}\mathbf{n}$ is a dyadic product.  In index notation, $\mathbf{n}\mathbf{n} \equiv n_i n_j$. Therefore, $\mathbf{n}\mathbf{n} \cdot \int \mathbf{x} \times \boldsymbol{\omega} \text{d}V \equiv n_i n_j \int e_{jmn} x_m \omega_n dV$.